# Bash - String replace of index-based substring

Tags: string, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file that includes, among other things, a json. The json contains passwords that need masking. The bash script responsible for the masking has no way of knowing the actual password itself, so its not a simple sed search-and-replace.

The passwords appear within the json under a constant key named "**password**" or "**Password**". Typically, the appearance is like -

```
...random content..."Password\":\"actualPWD\"...random content....
```

The bash script needs to change such appearances to -

```
...random content..."Password\":\"******\"...random content....
```

The quotes aren't important, so even ...random

```
content..."Password\":******...random content...
```

would work.

I reckon the logic would need to find the index of the ':' that appears after the text "Password"/"password" and then substring from that point on till the second occurrence of quote (") from there and replace the whole thing with *****. But I'm not sure how to do this with sed or awk. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 's/("[Pp]assword\\":\\")(.*?)(\\")/$1 . ("." x length $2) . $3/ge'
```

`/e` interprets the replacement part as code, so you can use the repetition operator `x` and repeat the dot `length $2` times.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Since JSON is structured, any approach based solely on regular expressions is bound to fail at some point unless the input is constrained in some way.  It would be far better (simpler and safer) to use a JSON-aware approach.

One particularly elegant JSON-aware tool worth knowing about is jq.  (Yes, the "j" is for JSON :-)

Assuming we have an input file consisting of valid JSON and that we want to change the value of every "password" or "Password" key to "******" (no matter how deeply nested the object having these keys may be), we could proceed as follows:

Place the following into a file, say mask.jq:

```
def mask(p): if has(p) then .[p] = "******" else . end;
.. |= if type == "object" 
      then mask("password") | mask("Password") else . end
```

Now suppose in.json has this JSON:

```
{"password": "secret", "details": [ {"Password": "another secret"} ]}
```

Then executing the command:

```
jq -f mask.jq in.json
```

produces:

```
{
  "password": "******",
  "details": [
    {
      "Password": "******"
    }
  ]
}
```

More on jq at https://github.com/stedolan/jq